# Determining if $f(g)=g^n$ is a homomorphism on an abelian group and finding its kernel.

Tags: group-theory

Determine if the map $f$ is a group homomorphism. Compute the kernel.

$G$ is an abelian group, $n > 1$, and $f: G \to G$ is defined by $f(g)=g^n$.

Well I showed that this is a homomorphism at least I think I did:
$$
\begin{align}
f(g_1 g_2) &= (g_1 g_2)^n \\
&= (g_1^n g_2^n) \\
&= (g_1^n)(g_2^n) \\
&= f(g_1)f(g_2)
\end{align}
$$

Now I don't know how to find $\ker(f) $, I know that $e$ would map to $e$ by default. I can't find any other elements that map to the identity and my friend told me that there was another element that maps to the identity. Any help?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, a very small abelian group, so you can see what happens to each element.

Comment: How did you go from step (1) to step (2)? You should use the fact that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @JonathanY. Hey, doing that. It looks like the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ would be dependent on n. So if $n = 2$, the kernel would be $[0]_4$ or $[2]_4$ and if $n = 4$, the kernel would be $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: @Rob, not quite; the main difference in behavior here would be between $n=1$ and $n>1$.

Comment: @JonathanY. So wait, if that's the case... Would the kernel be the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: Yes indeed, the kernel of any homomorphism is a (normal-)subgroup.

Comment: $kerf=${$g\in G:ord(g)|n$}

Comment: It looks like it would depend also on the order of $G$. For example, if $G$ is of prime order, the kernel of $f$ is trivial for all $n \ne |G|$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Haha points out in the comments, we have

$$\operatorname{ker}(f)=\{g\in G : \operatorname{ord}(g)\mid n\},$$

where $ \operatorname{ord}(g)$ is the order of $g$.

To see this, note that if  $k:=\operatorname{ord}(h)\mid n$ for some $h\in G$, then $n=k\ell$ for some $\ell\in\Bbb Z$, so that $$h^n=h^{k\ell}=(h^k)^\ell =e_G^\ell =e_G.$$

Can you show that there are no other elements of $\operatorname{ker}(f)$?

*Click, hover over, or tap the box below for a hint . . .*

> Suppose for a contradiction that other elements exist. What would the orders of such elements look like and why would these other elements be sent to $e_G$ under $f$?